# What's the number of possible five-card poker hands drawn without replacement?

Tags: combinatorics, poker

So we know a standard deck has 52 cards and it's asking the number of possible 5 card hands we could get from it without replacement which means without putting them back in the deck.

I thought about the usual formula of $52C5$ then multiplying it to $47C5$ => (47= 52-5), and so forth up until $7C5$ but I'm not sure that's the way.

If I could get a hint or an idea of if I'm going in the right way, that would really help me thanks!

Regards,

Comment: This is just $\binom {52}5$.

Comment: Are you looking at one hand of five cards or ten hands?  Why the $\sum$?

Comment: @Henry My bad I just realized how this looks, it's 1 hand there should be no ∑

Comment: What you write still makes no sense.  Why are you multiplying $\binom {52}5$ by anything?

Comment: @lulu The "without replacement" made me think of probabilities "without replacement" and how they are calculated. Which made me want to use it in this instance but after typing this comment out, I realize it doesn't make sense for me to use it for combinations. Thank you for pointing that out to me, I guess the answer is just $52C5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assuming one hand is drawn

The question is equivalent to asking how many ways we can select $5$ objects from $52$ objects. As there is no $2$nd hand that one draws from the deck, the condition of replacement is redundant as the process already terminates after picking a deck of $5$ cards. Furthermore, all the cards in the deck are distinct. Hence, the answer simply is $52 \choose 5$.

### Assuming ten hands are drawn

The condition of replacement makes a difference if ten hands are drawn consecutively, as the size of the deck shrinks by $5$ after every choice. Here, again, we must consider $2$ situations:

**Assuming order of selection matters**
In this case, your answer is correct, i.e.

$$\prod_{k=0}^9 {7 + 5k \choose 5}$$

**Assuming order of selection does not matter**
There are $10!$ ways to draw $10$ equivalent hands. Hence, in this case, the answer is
$$\frac{1}{10!}\cdot\prod_{k=0}^9 {7 + 5k \choose 5}$$

Comment: Oh! Adding the ten hands part helped me understand even more, thanks!